# SQL Server Management Studio connection error 233 - no process is on the other end of the pipe

Tags: sql-server, database-connection

I can't connect to SQL Server 2014 database engine from SSMS and get an error 233 and "no process at the end of the pipe".

It was working yesterday but not anymore after a Win10 update. I have rebooted, Shared Memory, Named Pipes, TCP/IP are all enabled, TCP/IP has been set to 127.0.0.1 and I'm using Windows Authentication.

I haven't tried to reinstall the software yet. Any suggestions please?

Comment: This link will guide you to get rid off this problem : http://www.windowstechupdates.com/microsoft-sql-server-error-233-no-process-is-on-the-other-end-of-the-pipe/

Comment: Thanks I'll take a look. Re-installation also seems to have helped. I'm also considering going back to local databases :-(